# Change of ip address after devstack installation

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have installed Devstack on Ubuntu.

But now I have changed my network connection and I have a new IP address.

I am not able to open the openstack dashboard in the browser.

How to make this installation independent of an IP address? Is it possible?

And is it always required to have a network connection to use devstack?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure your apache is started, as unstack.sh might kill it.

  ```
  service apache2 start # Ubuntu
  service httpd start # RHEL
  ```
- To run dashboard on a independent IP address do the following:

  ```
  cd /opt/stack/horizon
  python manage.py runserver XXX:8000
  ```

  Where XXX is IP. And please make sure you are able to ping your VM if you use devstack inside virtual machine, otherwise you won't access the dashboard.

However if host machine IP has changed there are more things need to be changed, there are also IP addresses in nova.conf and other configs.. **AFAIK the easiest way to update all IPs is to re-run devstack.**

- Devstack doesn't require network connection to be executed the second time.

  > Setting OFFLINE=True in localrc enables stack.sh to run multiple times without an Internet connection. [Link](http://devstack.org/guides/single-vm.html)

Thus to resolve your problem **set OFFLINE=True and run ./stack.sh**